# Speed up sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure I have to execute every time an application do some deletion. My question is, if anyone of you know some way, to speed up this stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @CID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @CID = @CategoryId


DELETE FROM Elements 
WHERE CategoryId = @CID
AND ParentId IS NOT NULL
AND ParentId NOT IN (SELECT ElementId FROM Elements WHERE CategoryId = @CID)


WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT  > 0)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Elements
    WHERE CategoryId = @CID
    AND ParentId IS NOT NULL
    AND ParentId NOT IN (SELECT ElementId FROM Elements WHERE CategoryId = @CID)
END
```

Here the structure:

```
Element 1
Element 2
    Element 2.1
    Element 2.2
    Element 2.3
        Element 2.3.1
        Element 2.3.2
Element 3
...
```

If for example "Element 2" is deleted, all child elements have to be deleted too.

**How the query works:**
If I delete "Element 2" and the stored procedure is executed, the first deletion statement will delete "Element 2.1", "Element 2.2" and "Element 2.3" because its ParentId (the ElementId of "Element 2") can not be found in the table. After that the second deletion statement will be executed. This time the same statement can not find any ElementIds of the Elements that are deleted the execution before.

**Important:**
Before the stored procedure is executed, the application has deleted one element. After that the whole structure will be saved. After that all elements which parents not existing, will be deleted through by the stored procedure.

The environment is an SQL Server 2008 R2.
Thank you in advance!

André

Comment: I don't understand what the 2nd delete statement is for. Surely it is redundant, as the 1st delete will have removed all the necessary `Elements`?

Comment: it doesn't look as if the second delete does anything different from the first as already pointed out.

Comment: It is a tree structure. If you delete an element that has childrens, the childrens have to be deleted too.

Comment: @Andre you are not deleting any children. Both queries do exactly the same.

Comment: @jeroenh yes I do, all elements are in the same table. The ParentId reference some other elemts ElementId

Comment: @Andre Do you have a trigger or a cascade or something that will automatically set `ParentId` to NULL when the parent is deleted? If so, I would advise you to post *all* relevant information about your question - we are not mind-readers! If not, then my original point stands - both deletes do the same thing so the 2nd one is redundant.

Comment: @RB. I have no trigger that sets ParentId to NULL. ParentId is only in one special case (if it is the root element) NULL.

Comment: @Andre In that case, you can speed up your stored procedure (very, very slightly) by removing the 2nd delete statement - it doesn't do anything!

Comment: @Andre you're wrong. Though I was wrong too: you're not deleting any *parents*. The second delete statement is exactly the same as the first, so how can they possibly delete other records?

Comment: @jeroenh see my new edit to the post. I hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Node NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @Node = 'Element 2.3'

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
  Node NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
, ParentNode NVARCHAR(50) NULL 
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Node, ParentNode)
VALUES 
('Element 1', NULL),
('Element 2', NULL),
('Element 2.1', 'Element 2'),
('Element 2.2', 'Element 2'),
('Element 2.3', 'Element 2'),
('Element 2.3.1', 'Element 2.3'),
('Element 2.3.2', 'Element 2.3'),
('Element 3', NULL)

; WITH nodes (Node) AS 
(
SELECT d.Node
FROM @temp d
WHERE d.Node = @Node

UNION ALL

SELECT d.Node
FROM @temp d
JOIN nodes d3 ON d3.Node = d.ParentNode
)

DELETE FROM t
FROM @temp t
JOIN nodes n ON t.Node = n.Node

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
```